# How to convert a language to lists, Racket

Tags: list, parsing, racket

I am making a parser in racket and I have the following error

```
map: contract violation
;   expected: list?
;   given: (language:lenguajito '(& varmain1 varmain2))
; [,bt for context]
```

I understand the error, basically map requires a list but I am passing it my language and it takes it as such. Is there a way to get the list '(& varmain1 varmain2) that I want?

In my define-pass i want to change my name vars, so I have

```lisp
(define-pass rename-var2 : lenguajito (ir) -> lenguajito ()
    (Main : Main (ir) -> Main () 
    [(funMain ([,i* ,t*] ...) (,s* ...)) 
                        (let* ([vars (vars-main ir)]
                                [tabla (asigna vars)]
                                [i*-n (map (lambda (v) (Expr v tabla)) i*)]
                                [s*-n (map (lambda (v) (Sents v tabla)) s*)])    
                            `(funMain ([,i*-n ,t*] ...) (,s*-n ...)  ))]

    [(funMain ([,i* ,t*] ...) (,s* ...) (,procs* ... )) 
                        (let* ([vars (vars-main ir)]
                                [tabla (asigna vars)]
                                [i*-n (map (lambda (v) (Expr v tabla)) i*)]
                                ;[s*-n (map (lambda (v) (Sents v tabla)) s*)]
                                ;this is the error, is not a list but I want to tranform for apply map
                                ;[procs*-n (map (lambda (v) (Procs v tabla)) procs*)]                              
                                )
                            `(funMain ([,i*-n ,t*] ...) (,s* ...) (,procs* ... )))])

    (Procs : Procs (ir h)  -> Procs () 
        ;patrones de Procs
        [(met ,i   ([,i* ,t*] ...) ,t  (,s* ...));other cases...
```

My grammar is as follows

```lisp
(define-language lenguajito
  (terminals
   (constante (c))
   (primitivo (pr))
   (tipo (t))
   (id (i)))

  (Main (m)
        (funMain ())
        ;(funMain ([i* t*] ...) )
        ;(funMain ([i* t*] ...) e)
        (funMain ([i* t*] ...) (s* ... ))
        (funMain ([i* t*] ...) (s* ... ) (procs* ... ))
        )

  (Procs (procs)
         ;(procs* ... procs)
         (met i   ([i* t*] ...) t (s* ... ))
         (fun  i  ([i* t*] ...)   (s* ... ))
         )

  (Sents (s)
         (if-sen e0 s0 s1)
         (if-sen e0 s0)
         (while-sen e0 s0)
         e*
         ;(e* ...)
         )

  (Expr (e)
        c
        i
        (i t)
        pr
        (return e)
        (pr e0 e1)
        ))
```

I have tried for-each and list but no results

Comment: Which `map` causes the issue? What program are you testing against? In general, please provide a program that can be run, so that we can reproduce the problem.